# How to make Binary patterns

Tags: binary

Ok so I'm new here but I just got into binary programs. Yes I know its like dinosaur old but I find the interesting patterns fun. Which got me to thinking is there a binary patterns program. Where I put in a pattern and it gives me the next in line?

Comment: You mean pattern recognition as in image processing(facial recognition) and stuff?

Comment: Please link to something that shows us what you're asking for. Is it like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Pattern_(Image_generation)?  Please give us an example of the kind of input and output that you'd expect.